# Can anyone tell me how to remove/handle "java.net.BindException: Address already in use"

Tags: java, hibernate, sockets, serversocket

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use

    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)

    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:174)

    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:139)

    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)

    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:70)

    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionHelper.createServerSocketChannel(ServerConnectionHelper.java:158)

    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionHelper.start(ServerConnectionHelper.java:320)

    at org.restlet.Server.start(Server.java:590)

    at org.restlet.Component.startServers(Component.java:611)

    at org.restlet.Component.start(Component.java:538)

    at ucsRestService.service.UCSRestService.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It means some other process is using this port already.

Comment: Sounds like you already have a server sitting on that port and so are unable to start your UCSRestService. May be worth doing a `ps -ef | grep java` to see what java processes are running and make sure it's not another instance of your UCSRestService. i.e. Is there already a java process running your UCSRestService running that's taking up that port? If not then some other process is using it. Try another port.

Comment: `netstat -lnptu | grep java`

Answer (score 1):

In short, you are trying to create more then 1 server with the same host and port.

Answer (score 1):

There is some service/server listening on specified port. You have to change port of server/service you are trying to start or disable service/server occupying that port.

Answer (score 1):

One machine can only have one listener with a particular port number at a time. For multiple listeners, try different port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I also come across this error sometimes, when I'm working with -  esp. testing - socket applications.

If you create a socket, you have to **`close()`** it afterwards. If you don't, the next time you try to create a socket on the same port, you can't, since it is already occupied.

Try a different port and remember to always close ;) If you don't want to create a socket on a different port, I guess you have to restart your machine (or maybe just your network card).

---

If you can't call `close()` directly, because the sockets are hidden by a framework, you should terminate that framework properly. It then will manage to close all it's resources (at least if it's a reasonable framework).